# How to make Access ODBC Export to DB2 create a NVARCHAR field, or use ccsid 1200 vs. 37

Tags: ms-access, odbc, db2-400

I am trying to export a table from Access 365 to an ODBC database, in this case DB2 for i. I have a recent IBM i Access Client Solutions ODBC driver, and set up a file DSN. This works for some tables, but for others, I get an error:

> [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver] Column 14: CWBNL0107 - Converted 46 bytes, 1 errors found beginning at offset 7 (scp=1202 tcp=37 siso=1 pad=0 sl=46 tl=255)(#30200) [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver]Error in assignment. (#30019)

Let's get some version numbers out there:

```
Access 365
IBM i: v7.2
IBM i Access Client Solutions 1.8.0.1
IBM i CCSID 37
Windows 10 USA
```

In column 14 the first string with non-ASCII characters has a smart quote at offset 7. This is a unicode character. I could try filtering these things out, but that would be a royal pain in the neck. It would be better if there was some configuration that would tell DB2 to use CCSID 1200 for columns that could contain these non-ASCII characters. Does anyone know how I might do that?

I found a setting in the ODBC driver to allow it to ignore invalid characters, but that does not actually ignore the character, it inserts a different non-printable character in there. For example U+2019 which is a curly apostrophe converts to an x'3F' which is a control character in EBCDIC. Actually, this could cause problems with a 5250 screen. Like I said, I can blank those out, but I would rather see an NVARCHAR field.

Comment: What creates the destination table?  Does it already exist or does Access 365 create it?   I don't believe that the ODBC driver will decide the colums types.  That is set when the table is created.

Comment: The table does not exist pre-export. The field type in the Access Database has an attribute that specifies unicode, so the database knows that the field could have unicode characters in it.